# The interesting tab on other sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, homepage, interesting-page

See [Jeff Atwood - Stack Overflow Homepage Changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/).

This seems to work quite good, but it leaves me wondering...

- Would this behave well on other SE 2.0 sites?
- How can I get this to work on other SE 2.0 sites? Or will it be implemented?

Does anyone know of a GreaseMonkey script that has the same effect?

Comment: I'm guessing it wouldn't be that useful on the majority of SEs because of their relatively low volume.  On Stack Overflow this feature is important because questions get bumped off the front (active) page within half an hour; on a typical SE, questions might remain on the front page for a couple of *days*.  I'm sure that once other sites start to hit Stack Overflow's scale, the team will consider implementing the feature there.

Comment: This feature has other benefits than scalability, in which I am more interested. Instead of giving everyone the same list of questions on the frontpage, I consider it would be better to provide a list of questions that actually matters to the user. Actually, it was implemented on other sites too but it got removed, see waffles' answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Would this behave well on other SE 2.0
>   sites?

**NO**, not a chance, the current algorithm applies to short time frames and was designed to solve Stack Overflows problem.

> How can I get this to work on other SE 2.0 sites? Or will it be implemented?

How do you expect it to work? It was designed to solve a problem the smaller SE 2.0 sites do not have.

---

Anyway, you can access it from any site eg: http://meta.stackoverflow.com?tab=interesting

Interesting was specifically designed to give questions on SO more front page time. At peek we see over 200 questions an hour at SO, even Super User, a moderately busy site *only* sees 150 questions a day on a busy day.

So when you chuck the "interesting question" [algorithm at Super User](https://superuser.com/?tab=interesting) and scroll to the bottom, you can see some slots that got freed.

Overall this feature is not designed for sites that do not have these scaling issues.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore... :-(

Comment: @TomWij - can you define "doesn't work"? I get a page, but I've no way of knowing whether it's what you expect or not.

Comment: @ChrisF: On StackOverflow, you see an interesting tab, the provided link would have done the same for other SE 2.0 sites. But now the tab is gone and it doesn't have the same `interesting` behaviour anymore, it shows the old `activity` behaviour...

Comment: @TomWij - I see.

Comment: @waffles: Thank you, it seems to work again. The 'interesting' version just results in a better front page for me, I don't see any problem accessing it by URL... :-)

Comment: @TomWij glad it works for you , eventually we will possibly roll out a similar feature for other big sites

Answer (score 1):

If you go to http://stackexchange.com, you can generate a list of questions across all SE 2.0 sites matching certain tags. Each tag in the set can be

- A tag on a specific site
- A tag on all sites
- Not a particular tag, but all questions from a given site.

Additionally features:

- Switch between multiple different tag sets
- Views of "Activity", "Newest", or "No Answers"
- if your accounts are linked, you can pull in your interesting tags across SE 2.0 sites.

It can't do the fancy filtering by question and answer scores, although a GreaseMonkey script wouldn't be able too either.  (Plus scores across sites aren't comparable.)

Comment: Sorry, `tab`, not `tag`. And yes, a script can do it because the example people could play with was javascript.